# How can I install Ubuntu Server (20.04 LTS) on Raspberry Pi 4 with a CLEAN setup?

Tags: boot, server

Sorry if the title sounds confusing. Basically I would like to make a fresh/clean install of Ubuntu Server on my Pi, but the Raspberry Pi version only comes as preinstalled, and I would like to go through the inital setup like you would on a nornmal version. I tried downloading the ARM based version, but I when I tried writing to my microSD card with the Raspberry Pi Imager software, it wouldn't load at all.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would like to know why you want to set it up that way? As I understand, the Pi bootloader works differently, and that's why the preferred method is a preinstalled image. Anything you can do during the setup, you can tweak afterwards on the installation. Please clarify in your post what exactly it is that you want to tweak on the preinstalled image, and I believe there will be solutions to that. I've done just that on my RasPi server.

Comment: Hey! I wasn't sure what comes with it because its preinstalled, and I had this sense that I won't be able to configure it to my liking, you know when you go through the inital setup normally? I guess thats fine then if its not possible and you can change things after. Like you know when you buy a laptop and it has stuff installed already? I think I was worried it might be like that, haha.

Comment: I would say that the preinstalled image is the closest you can come to a "clean" setup. Afterwards I would recommend you change username/password and hostname of course. And you can also tweak locale/keyboard settings and installed packages afterwards, just to name a few.

Comment: That's grand! Thanks, mate. :-)